# php Failed to listen on 172.0.0.1:8080 (reason: Can't assign requested address)

Tags: php, localhost, server

I was using the php server(?) with the command line, in the terminal on OSX

```
php -S 172.0.0.1:8080
```

it was all working great, but suddenly started giving me the error:

```
Failed to listen on 172.0.0.1:8080 (reason: Can't assign requested address)
```

I closed the terminal and restarted the system to close anything that might be running but still the same error.

It gives that error no matter what address I give (as long as it's a valid one). I was just working on a web page, loading it with the server over and over, can't think of anything that I did to make it happen. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might be too simplistic but don't you mean to use `127.0.0.1` ? Unless you are actually assigned `172.0.0.1`, I'm surprised this has ever worked before.

Comment: wow, that's pretty embarrassing. It is the problem. I have no idea how that happened since I used the up arrow to repeat the command. but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

for me this issue accorded because I mess-up with  `/etc/hosts` File , I was using address `::1` on that file remove it solved my issue